# Sharing connections in karate gatling load tests

Tags: karate

https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_protocol/#http-protocol-connection-sharing

How do you share connections using `karateProtocol`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported directly. This is an opportunity for you to contribute to Karate :)

Note that this may require you to implement a custom `HttpClient` which is not too complicated - if you know Java: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-mock-servlet#switching-the-http-client

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for replying so fast. You have been amazing at support!

Comment: @ShawnLim thanks :) to be honest this is an area we haven't researched much, I was just reading this: https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/performance.html - and it looks like the Apache HttpClient does re-use connections by default. but you can investigate. also look at the code where we set up apache, maybe there is something extra we can do there: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-apache/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/apache/ApacheHttpClient.java